# font-face are not working with rollup config - component library

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, rollup

I have custom component library written in React (rollup to build). I don't want to use createglobalstyle BCS its broke performance in an external project. I added CSS file with font-face (relative path) but these fonts are not working in external projects. Do u have any idea how to fix it?
src

- components (folders)
- index.css with

  @font-face {
  font-family: 'font1';
  font-display: swap;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url(assets/fonts/font1/heavy/heavy.woff2)
  }
  h1{
  margin: 2.75rem 0 1.05rem;
  font-family: 'font1';
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.15;
  color:red;
  }

Rollupconfig plugins :

```
[    postcss({
        extract: false,
        plugins: [autoprefixer]
    }),
    babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    localResolve(),
    resolve({
        browser: true
    }),
    commonjs(),
    filesize(),
    copy({
        targets: [{ src: 'src/assets', dest: 'build' }]
    }),
    url({
        // by default, rollup-plugin-url will not handle font files
        include: ['**/*.woff', '**/*.woff2'],
        // setting infinite limit will ensure that the files 
        // are always bundled with the code, not copied to /dist
        limit: Infinity
      }),
      modulepreload({
        prefix: 'fonts',
        index: 'src/assets/fonts/font1/heavy/heavy.woff2',
      })

];
```

When I use that library in external projects I see all style like color:red etc. but font-face is not working :(

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

I have the feeling that you just wrongly entered the source of your font.

Try something like this:

```
@font-face { 
font-family: 'font1';
font-display: swap;
font-weight: 900;
src: url("../assets/fonts/font1/heavy/heave.woff2");
```

}